# Access XML data via mxj

Tags: xml, go

Using `mxj` to pull XML as a map, but can't access the internal map data using `["key"]["key"]` syntax. Getting err:

```
.\mxjt.go:28:31: invalid operation: conf["directory"]["item_list"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

However, the child maps do? I must be missing something here.

My golang:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/clbanning/mxj"
)

var (
    localfile string = os.Getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\tmp-phoneconfig.cfg"
)

func main() {

    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(localfile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    conf, err := mxj.NewMapXml(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("err:", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(conf["directory"]["item_list"])
}
```

My XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- $RCSfile: 000000000000-directory~.xml,v $  $Revision: 1.3 $ -->
<directory>
        <item_list>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1002       Shelly </ln>
                        <fn> Shelly </fn>
                        <ct> 1002 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1003       Chris </ln>
                        <fn> Chris </fn>
                        <ct> 1003 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1004       Extra </ln>
                        <fn> Extra </fn>
                        <ct> 1004 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1005       Ray </ln>
                        <fn> Ray </fn>
                        <ct> 1005 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1006       Kitchen </ln>
                        <fn> Kitchen </fn>
                        <ct> 1006 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1007       Scott </ln>
                        <fn> Scott </fn>
                        <ct> 1007 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1008       Heath </ln>
                        <fn> Heath </fn>
                        <ct> 1008 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1009       Andy </ln>
                        <fn> Andy </fn>
                        <ct> 1009 </ct>
                </item>
                <item>
                        <ln> 1010       John </ln>
                        <fn> John </fn>
                        <ct> 1010 </ct>
                </item>
                </item_list>
</directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update.

Use NewMapXmlReader(), ValuesForPath() for XML.

```
func main() {
    file, err := os.Open(localfile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    m, err := mxj.NewMapXmlReader(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    item, err := m.ValuesForPath("directory.item_list.item")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, v := range item {
        data := v.(map[string]interface{})
        fmt.Println(data["ln"], data["fn"], data["ct"])
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to get say.. `Shelly` from directory/item_list/item/fn. How would I pull that?

Comment: @user3051040 Update post. it's NewMapXmlReader(), ValuesForPath() .